# snmp trap specific trap code

Tags: snmp, snmptrapd, snmp-trap

I'm building a SNMP agent and now working on the trap message. Before I begin to write the code of the trap message, I have question:
 In SNMPv1 what is the specific trap code ?  Everywhere I  searched I get just  superficial definition and I want to get a deep definition with the possibilities of what it can contain.

Comment: One question per question please

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An SNMPv1 [trap PDU](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1157#section-4.1.6) contains the following items:

1. Object Type generating the trap (this is an `OID` of type `NOTIFICATION-TYPE`)
2. Address of generating object (an IP address)
3. Generic Trap Data - one of the enumerations listed (0==coldStart, 1==warmStart ... 6==Enterprise)
4. Enterprise Trap Data - 0 or the specified enterprise trap data
5. Timestamp - timestamp trap was generated
6. Variable Bindings.

The *generic trap data* items 0-5 are defined explicitly in the spec as to what they mean, once you hit `6` (enterprise), then it is completely up to the definition supplied in the enterprise MIB. Unless you're actually loading and interpreting the content of the MIB that *defines* what the value means you can't actually understand what it means. If we look at the [`UCD-SNMP-MIB`](http://www.net-snmp.org/docs/mibs/UCD-SNMP-MIB.txt), it defines two trap types:

```
ucdTraps OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { ucdavis 251 }

ucdStart NOTIFICATION-TYPE
    STATUS  current
    DESCRIPTION
    "This trap could in principle be sent when the agent start"
    ::= { ucdTraps 1 }
    
ucdShutdown NOTIFICATION-TYPE
    STATUS current
    DESCRIPTION
    "This trap is sent when the agent terminates"
    ::= { ucdTraps 2 }
```

These correspond to OIDs `.1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.251.1` and `.1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.251.2` respectively.

The OID is interpreted as `.1.3.6.1.4.1` == enterprises base, `2021` == UC Davis, `251` == ucdTraps and the trailing `1` or `2` is for usdStartup and usdShutdown respectively.

These traps would set the trap data type to `6` and, as they don't specify any content of the enterprise data field, it would not be interpretable.

Finally for *variable data*, it's a sequence of OID, value pairs, and needs to be unwrapped as specified ASN.1 data.

The `coldStart` OID is `.1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.5.1` - the base definitions are in [the SNMPv2 MIB](http://www.net-snmp.org/docs/mibs/SNMPv2-MIB.txt) file for coldStart, warmStart and authenticationFailure, the definitions of linkDown and linkUp can be found in [RFC2863](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2863#section-3.1.15).

to be honest, I wouldn't bother trying to interpret the data unless I was armed with the spec for the trap as without it you would have no way of understanding what it means.

Comment: It seems to me that you avoided specifically answering the OPs question: What value is correct value for what the OP calls `specific trap code`, what the [RFC](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1157#section-4.1.6)  calls `specific-trap` and what you call `Enterprise Trap Data`? (And why do you use a completely different name for that field than the RFC?) The integer is mandatory. In the case of e.g. `ucdStart`, is the correct value for `specific-trap` 0 (for "unspecified") or 1 (for the last integer  of the OID for `ucdStart`)?